# Showing this error - Getting Unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors, build.gradle

i'll Check id's and Everything Was Right!! but I don't know what is the problem.

errors :

Unresolved reference: synthetic

Unresolved reference: btnLogin

Unresolved reference: btnSignUp

Unresolved reference: etEmailAddress

Unresolved reference: etPassword

My LoginActivity

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
        login()
    }

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

}

private fun login(){
    val email = etEmailAddress.text.toString()
    val password = etPassword.text.toString()


    if (email.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email/password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this){
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

}

My AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".activities.ProfileActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".activities.ResultActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.QuestionActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignupActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.LoginIntro" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my Build.Gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 32

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cheezycode.quizzed"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
namespace 'com.cheezycode.quizzed'
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.0.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this once-
You missed the initialization.

Suppose you don't want to do initialization use [View binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

USING VIEW BINDING AS PER your gradle use

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

     private var _binding: ActivityLoginBinding? = null
        private val binding get() = _binding!!
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
        login()
    }

    binding.btnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

}

private fun login(){
    val email = binding.etEmailAddress.text.toString()
    val password = binding.etPassword.text.toString()


    if (email.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email/password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return
    }

 override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
```

Option 2-

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
      private var btnLogin: Button? = null
        private var btnSignUp: Button? = null
        private var etEmailAddress: EditText? = null
        private var etPassword: EditText? = null
        lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)
            btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp)
            etEmailAddress = findViewById(R.id.etEmailAddress)
            etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword)
    
            btnLogin?.setOnClickListener {
                login()
            }
    
            btnSignUp?.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
    
        }
    
        private fun login() {
            val email = etEmailAddress?.text.toString()
            val password = etPassword?.text.toString()
    
    
            if (email.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Email/password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return
            }
    
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this) {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
```